# SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I get the following error in IE 9 `SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined` only when in compatability mode. the line causing this error is

```
JSON.stringify(togObj.Answers)
```

The error does not occur in ie (non-compatability mode), Chrome or Firefox. 
Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: It seems that the `JSON` object is not defined. Have a look at http://json.org/js.html for adding JSON support.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See here for a blog post explaining the situation: [Resolve JSON is Undefined Error in Internet Explorer](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/resolve-json-is-undefined-error-in.html)

Include the [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in your page and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 24):

JSON is [not available in compatibility mode IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836458(v=vs.94).aspx):

> Not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards.

Since you shouldn't be using (or worse, reyling on ) compatibility modes in the first place, you should switch IE to standards-mode by adding a valid doctype.

Comment: I accidentally switched on the compatibility mode and got the error. +1 for guiding me.

Comment: Note that IE iframes "inherit" the parent frame's document mode. So if might need the JSON lib well beyond IE7 if you might get embedded in pages you do not control.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, JSON is defined natively in modern browsers, but not in IE. You need to import a library. For example, http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Answer (score 2):

I have done LOCAL Jquery added .NEt 2.0 code testing, it works fine without any problem.
But after migrate the code to IIS v6 server then access from same IE browser, then problem appear "JSON" undefined. 
After read this recommendation, downlode the file json2.js and add below into source code.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
```

EVERYTHING WORKING Fine.

Good Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery library at your page, than you could use `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: @FilipCornelissen : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ It requires 1.4.1 jquery version. Also, verify that your json is correct. Try passing a demo json string to this function and verify.

Comment: from that same page: "Where the browser provides a native implementation of JSON.parse, jQuery uses it to parse the string." and (simplified) from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js: 'parseJSON: function( data ) { return window.JSON.parse( data ); }'. 

Conclusion, does not work natively in IE8 or lower.

Comment: "if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse )" just attempts to parse it with browsers native JSON function. If it fails there that means your JSON is wrong as per its specs. Can you please send the JSON you are trying to parse? FYI: jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE 6/7/8.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update (2013!) to the links provided above-

Per http://www.json.org/js.html, a link at the bottom of the page will refer you to the latest implementation:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

You need to include json2.js

see [json2 inclusion](http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=405#comment-2181)

for more details. There are cases where we have to deal with cases where clients use IE7 standards. So our code had to cater to such cases too. Ours being a retail website is accessed by hundreds of clients who use IE7 standards. Including json2 solves this issue