# Internet Explorer Error SCRIPT5009: '$$' is undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a custom jquery script:

```
var AppFunctions = {
        version: 0.1,
        end: function () {
            return false;
        }
    };

if (!window.$$) { window.$$ = AppFunctions; }
```

where each function can be called as

`$$.settings.validateEmail();`

and in JS file it is defined as

```
$$.settings = function () { };

$$.settings.validateEmail= function () {
    if($('.email').val().length <= 0) {
          alert('enter email');
          return false;
    }
};
```

all the browser are running the script perfectly fine, but IE6 and IE9 with compatibility view gives an error saying

> Error SCRIPT5009: '$$' is undefined

can you anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: @AndreasAL as I said it is a character defined to used this particular script [i have updated the question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as I figure out that the problem was not this syntax i.e. $$. Because the jquery plugin I was using it had a JSON method in it and because of it these error was showing and for this, I found the solution at [SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332362/script5009-json-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `var $$ = jQuery;` on the top of the code.

You can also wrap your code in

```
(function($$) { 
    $$.settings = function () { };

    $$.settings.validateEmail= fuenter code herenction () {
        if($('.email').val().length <= 0) {
              alert('enter email');
              return false;
        }
}; })(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if (!window.$$) { 
    $$ = window.$$ = AppFunctions;
}
```

and and at first in your global scope:

```
var $$;
```