# Can jquery.json.js and Json2.js be used at the same time?

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am looking at an application someone else made and it was made using "jquery.json.js" plugin.

However I get errors like this in IE 7

> SCRIPT5009: 'JSON' is undefined

This lead me to posts like [json is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332362/script5009-json-is-undefined)  what say to use json2.js.

I added this script and it does solve my problem. I am however wondering if these 2 scripts could conflict.

jquery.json.js seems to be a port of json2 from what I read but it does not obvisouly have IE 7 support.

jquery.json.js also seems to have extra methods as when I remove it and just use json2 I get a whole bunch of errors as the app is dependent on some methods from jquery.json.js such as `$.secureEvalJSON is not a function`

Comment: In what order did you include them?

Comment: OK why though? It seemed to work but I did not fully test it all.

Comment: jQuery.json.js relies on the window.JSON object which doesn't exist in IE7. json2.js adds that object in IE7, therefore it must exist before jquery.json.js so that jquery.json.js can access the window.JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can and should. json2.js just creates a global JSON object that is available natively on most modern browser except IE7.  Import json2.js **FIRST** because your other scripts needs the JSON object.

Comment: Do you mean jquery.json.js? As json2.js is the file that is what made it work in IE7

Comment: Most browser have the JSON object built in so you can do stuff like JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() (which your jquery.json.js is probably using). However IE7 does not have this JSON object built-in so you have to define the JSON object for IE7 by including the json2.js script. So yes json2.js is what will make it work in IE7 just include it first.

Comment: Ah so the jquery.json.js uses those 2 methods internally and gives I guess more methods like $.secureEvalJSON where json2 just makes all browsers be able to do basic json?

Comment: You are correct sir. Its a good habit to always include json2.js in any page that will be using JSON, and its simply to let IE7 know what the JSON object is.