# Why JSON is undefined when accessing deployed website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, razor, deployment

Working on an MVC4 website (development is still in a very early stage at the moment), I debug it through IIS Express (nothing fancy here, I started from the `Internet Application` template then just F5 away.

I have this piece of javascript:

```
function packData(F) {
     F.data.value = Base64.encode(
         JSON.stringify({
             'myField': 'myData'
         })
     );
     F.submit();
}
```

This function is called from a partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "autoMagic", controllerName: "Magic", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "autoMagicForm" }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("data")            
        <input type="button" value="go!" onclick="packData(this.form)" />
    }
```

The form is supposed to act as a "mock" of an incoming POST request.

What I did:

- Publish is set to `File System` (on a local folder on my pc) with precompile enabled, I then copy-pasted the whole folder over to the remote server. I haven't setup any web.config transformation (yet).
- The browser is the same: Internet Explorer 10
- On the remote server, the folder is setup as an Application in IIS, with its own Application Pool (Framework 4.0, Integrated)

What I see:

- On IIS Express (localhost) everything works as expected: both the javascript function and the invoked controller successfully perform their magic.
- On the deploy server (http:testserver/site) IE complains that **JSON is undefined**.

Looks like I'm missing something ?

I tried capturing Network traffic with IE's F12 Tool but I don't see any `404`.

Comment: check if any js resource(probably like json.js or json2.js) is getting 404 response.

Comment: F12 tool (Network -> Start Capture -> CTRL+F5) doesn't show any 404

Comment: Beats me, thought of problem mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332362/script5009-json-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

In early versions of IE(less IE8) JSON object (window.JSON)is not defined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON